# NAry Tree implementation In C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

Here I implement N-Ary tree in C#.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class tree {
        public int info;
        public tree child;
        public tree siblings;

        public tree(int data)
        {
            info = data;
        }
    }

    public class NAryTree
    {
        public tree ROOT;
        public tree search(tree root, int data)
        {
            if (root == null)
                return null;

            if (data == root.info)
                return root;

            tree t = search(root.child, data);
            if (t == null)
                t = search(root.siblings, data);

            return t;
        }

        public void CreateNarray( int[] data)
        {  tree temp  = null;
            if(ROOT != null)
             temp = search(ROOT,data[0]);

            if (temp == null)
            {
                temp = new tree(data[0]);

            }
            if (this.ROOT == null)
                ROOT = temp;
            tree parent = temp;

            for (int j = 0; j < data[1]; j++)
            {
                // for first child
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    parent.child = new tree(data[j+2]);
                    parent = parent.child;
                }
                //for all other childs
                else
                {
                    parent.siblings = new tree(data[j+2]);
                    parent = parent.siblings;
                }

            }

        }

        public void Print()
        {
            preorder(ROOT);
        }
       public void preorder( tree p)
         {
        if(p==null)
        return;
         Console.WriteLine(""+p.info);
         preorder(p.child);

        preorder(p.siblings);
           }
    }




    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            NAryTree naryTree = new NAryTree();
            //1st element in each row is node Value, 2nd - no of child, ,>=3rd....=>value of child

              int[][] data={new int[] {1,3,2,3,4}, new int[] {2,3,1,6,50},new int[]{3,3,8,9,10},new int[]{4,3,0,0,0,0}};


              for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++ )
              {
                 naryTree.CreateNarray(  data[i]);
              }

              naryTree.Print();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for My Sub Standard English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some points I would like to address to you, but I am missing a little bit the purpose of your exercise. From what I understand, every node of your tree can have only one child and only one sibling. Is it a feature or maybe you should change the `Tree` class to have as type for both `Child` and `Siblings` as `IEnumerable<Tree>`?

One thing that usually makes reviewer happy, is to give a consistant and understandable naming through the whole application. For example, I think it would improve readability renaming the class `Tree` to `Node`, and the field `Info` to `Value`.

I would avoid, if possible, the usage of fields and I would stick with public properties. A good explanation about why can be found [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/properties-vs-public-variables/). For now then, your `Tree` class should look like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Node Children { get; set; }
    public Node Siblings { get; set; }

    public Node(int data)
    {
        Value = data;
    }
}
```

If you are trying to implement a N-ary tree, I guess you would like that (as by definition), you won't have more than N children for each node. As you implemented it, as I was stating in my first request, you're only implementing a 1-ary tree. 
For a N-ary tree, an idea could be adding N as property of the NAryTree, and change the types accordingly to avoid having more than N children for each node.

For the `NAryTree`, if I only read to signatures of methods, I would get the wrong idea about what you're trying to do. `Print()` gives me the idea you're trying to display on screen the content of the tree, but `PreOrder()` leads me to think you're sorting an unsorted tree (so, this is a bad name), and `CreateNArray(int[] data)` makes me think you're creating a new N-Array from scratch (again, which is your purpose here? I can't understand if a better name would be `Initialize(int[] data)` or `Add(int[] data)`).
Another suggestion I would like to give you, is to extract an interface for your `NAryTree`: this would  Accordingly to what I was saying before, I would rename `Print()` to `ToString()` and return a `string` as type.
Maybe adding the `AddChild(int value)` to the `Node` class would help you to keep easier the implementation of the CreateNArray method, if I got what you're trying to do.